# Select item in ListView using value from Intent

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to select an item in a `ListView` based on a value I get from an Intent. [I've tried `ListView.setSelection`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92bDs.png), but it's not working.

```java
Intent i = this.getIntent();
String sp = i.getStringExtra("Sport");
for (int position = 0; position < sports.length; position++)
    if (sports[position].equals(sp)) {
        listView.setSelection(position);
    }
```

Here is the rest of the code, for context:

```java
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sport_item);
    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);
    String[] sports = new String[] {
        "Soccer",
        "Running",
        "Swimming",
        "Volleyball",
        "Tennis"
    };

    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.listview, R.id.textView, sports);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    Button btnSelect = findViewById(R.id.btnSelect);
    listView.setChoiceMode(listView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    
    btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (ListView.getCheckedItemPosition() != -1) {
                Intent i = new Intent(SportActivity.this, InformationActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("Sport", sports[listView.getCheckedItemPosition()]); |
                i.putExtra("Position", listView.getCheckedItemPosition());
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
                finish();
            } else
                Toast.makeText(SportActivity.this, "Ban chua lya chon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(SportActivity.this, "Sport selected :" + sports[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    
    Intent i = this.getIntent();
    String sp = i.getStringExtra("Sport");
    for (int position = 0; position < sports.length; position++)
        if (sports[position].equals(sp)) {
            listView.setSelection(position);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

show more code, post it in here. you should call `setSelected` only after setting adapter, before there is no content on list so nothing gets selected

in your case your problem is caused probably by comparing `String`s with `==` operator. in Java it compares objects and one obtained from `intent` and second one from array arent same objects, even if they have same content (they still are two objects in two separated placed in memory). use `equals` method for comparing only content

```
if(sports[position].equals(sp))
```

Comment: I added the code. i changed == -> equals but it's still the same

Comment: try to put `listView.setSelection` inside `new Runnable` and set it through `listView.post()` method. or you may move whole code from first screen (section starting from line with `getIntent()`) to `onResume` method

Comment: and never post screenshots of your code, post it as text in question, so it is easily selectable and copyable for further modifications/fixes for answering questions (like me)